# Draggable an element which is inside a droppable one

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have a draggable element that I put inside my droppables container and I want to drag it back. If it's out of the droppable container I want to destroy it.

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/155466/

And here is my jQuery code :

```
    $('.spell').draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  scope: 'drop',
  revert: 'invalid'
});
$('.spell-receiver').droppable({
  accept: '.spell',
  scope: 'drop',
  hoverClass: 'spell-receiver-border',
  drop: function(ev, ui) {
    $(this).empty();
    if ($(this).find('.spell').length === 0) {
      var droppedItem = $(ui.draggable).clone();
      $(this).append(droppedItem);
    }
  }
});
```

And my HTML code :

```
    <div class="stats-category">
  <div class="stats-content">
    <div class="spell ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"></div>
    <div class="spell ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"></div>
    <div class="spell ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"></div>
    <div class="spell ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="stats-header">Section 1</div>
  <div class="stats-content">
    <div class="spell-receiver ui-droppable"></div>
    <div class="spell-receiver ui-droppable"></div>
    <div class="spell-receiver ui-droppable"></div>
    <div class="spell-receiver ui-droppable"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="stats-header">Section 2</div>
  <div class="stats-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

I already tried to :

- add draggable() event at the end but the first div comes with the original
- use "stack" parameter
- modify z-index
- use append

I don't know what is going wrong, I can't only take the div I have put inside my droppable container but I can take both...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer :

Instead of `$(this).append(droppedItem);` or `$(this).append(droppedItem).draggable();` you should put `$(this).append(droppedItem.draggable());` otherwise the whole item will be considered as draggable.